# Wrong jasmine typings in Angular 8/9

Tags: angular, jasmine, typescript-typings

I created a new blank angular 9 project (`ng new my-app`). Then run: npm install and changed only this:

[image]

I added `.then()` as visual studio code typings report that expect matchers return *Promise*.

After running `npm test -> ng test`, I get:

```
ERROR in src/app/app.component.spec.ts:26:41 - error TS2339: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'boolean'.

26     expect(app.title).toEqual('my-app').then(() => { });
                                           ~~~~
```

So I removed the **@types/jasminewd2** from package.json and expect matchers are synchronous methods, they don't return promise, but booleans. Everything works as it should.

[image]

What have I missed here? Does anyone else has this problems. This came out of the box I mean default setup.

Comment: don't let an IDE affect your packge.json as it means that someone else using your code with another IDE might have breaking changes. you should look at the extensions added to VSCODE, they are probably the source of the problem. VSCode runs your `ng test script` but won't affect it so you'd better ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a known bug, already addressed by angular cli team:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/17493